# Is AWS IoT Device Gateway an MQTT broker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mqtt, aws-iot

I am trying to understand Amazon AWS IoT and I see there is a Device Gateway connected between Sensors/Actuators and AWS (Rules Engine). I understand Sensors/Actuators are MQTT Clients which can Publish/Subscribe to the topics.

> Device Gateway also supports Publish/Subscribe pattern is that means
>
> Device Gateway is also a MQTT Client ?
>
> Then where is the MQTT broker?
>
> OR  Device Gateway is Broker + communication interface to AWS-IoTservices?

I have attached an Image Amazon presentation on AWS IoT for the reference:

[image]

Comment: I am in the same situation: I don't know how to address the AWS MQTT Broker. How do I find out the url for the AWS DeviceGateway (MQTT Broker)? I need that, as I am using a ZwayMQTT Bridge.The link posted by hardillb doesn't supply this crucial piece of information. Matter of fact, the whole documentation is very high level and doesn't help me much to understand how to set things up.

Comment: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=712083

Answer (score 10):

The gateway is a MQTT broker, but not a fully compliant one. Some of the differences are:

- no retained message support
- no QOS2 support
- no message persistence

Full details can be found here http://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/protocols.html