# AWS IOT: Does the platform act as an MQTT broker?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, mosquitto, paho, hivemq

I just need to be sure whether I would need to use a separate library/provider such as Mosquitto and HiveMQ and integrate them with AWS IOT or would the amazon platform act as a self sufficient endtoend solution.

TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is AWS IoT Device Gateway an MQTT broker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34448185/is-aws-iot-device-gateway-an-mqtt-broker)

Answer (score 3):

The AWS IoT service includes an MQTT message broker.

Answer (score 0):

I am not into AWS IoT that deep, but:

When using a MQTT Broker, make sure that
* each device gets individual credentials 
* device cannot subscribe to topics of other devices (unless that is explicitly what you want).

BR,